# How can I toggle between Bootstrap 5.1.0 modals?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I simply copied the example from [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals), but the first modal is not hidden if I open the 2nd modal from within the modal popup. Why?

You can see that the backdrop is also a bit darker for the 2nd popup, which is because the 2nd one is simply overlayed on the 1st one, without hiding the prior modal.

I also tried it locally with same result: the 1st modal is never hidden.

Interestingly it works as expected on the bootstrap docs website...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button">Open first modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Modal 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Open second modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle2" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">Modal 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Back to first</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/neog0236/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your JSFiddle demo uses an older library version. When I update that it works. See the Highlights section of the [5.1.1 release notes](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2021/09/07/bootstrap-5-1-1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var myModalEl = document.querySelector('#scheduleMeetingModal');
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl);
myModal.hide();
```